# Send private message to Facebook page with nodejs

Tags: node.js, facebook

I'm trying to explore something about Facebook-chat-api provided on git and node.js. I know what I want but I can't find proper literature so please help me out.

I have a Facebook page and I have front-end html page with sockets + back-end node.js. On front-end I have text box. The idea is that I want to send whatever is in that text box to my page as a private message.

I know You can send message to a friend via this node plugin but I'm nut sure what to put as ID if You want to send a message to Yourself or page.

Using facebook-chat-api.

```
socket.on("REQ fmsgsend", function(mailData){
    facebook({email: "FB_EMAIL", password: "FB_PASSWORD"}, (err, api) => {
        if(err) return console.error(err);
        api.sendMessage(message.body, message.threadID);
    });
});
```

I would put text box string in message.body but I'm not sure how to detect thread ID. Am I going wrong way?

Comment: _“I know You can send message to a friend”_ – not via API; and the API is the only thing you are allowed to use if you want to automate anything on Facebook. If anything is trying to log in to Facebook using e-mail and password - it’s wrong. And there is no such thing as a “facebook-chat-api”.

Comment: I'm sorry but You are fully wrong. https://www.npmjs.com/package/facebook-chat-api

Comment: Just because someone named their package "Facebook Chat API", doesn't mean it is an official product - on the contrary, the mere fact that it uses the credentials of a personal profile directly to log in proves it is for sure not a Facebook product. (Doing that is _forbidden_ under their platform policy.) The documentation you linked to refers to the Messenger Platform, which is indeed a kind of chat - between a user and a bot that answers in the name of a page. But in no way is it intended or allowed to be used for chat between two users, which FB deliberately does not provide an API for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
var facbook = require("facebook-chat-api");

facbook({email: EMAIL@EMAIL.com, password: PASSWORD}, function callback (err, api) {
    if(err) return console.error(err);

    api.getUserID(FriendName, (err, dataF) => {
        if(err) return console.error(err);

        // Send the message to the best match (best by Facebook's criteria)

        var msg = "Hello my friend!";
        var threadID = dataF[0].userID;
        api.sendMessage(msg, threadID);
        api.logout(function(err){
            if(err) return console.error(err);
            console.log("logged out");
        });
    });
});
```

This code on node.js server sends a message to friend by name.
This code and it's functionalities are not approved by Facebook or Facebook-API.

Comment: What does FriendName stands for here, there can be many people with same name..!?

Comment: Any friend name <<string>> You have in a friend list. Yes it's true, that's why dataF is an array of users, or it was back then when I posted this.

Comment: This script is getting stopped with 2-3 messages now.. :(